# module not recognised by PyCharm

Tags: google-translate

google_trans_new. is not recognised by PyCharm, even though it's there in my site package library.  Please help.

(I heard about the module that allows you to access google translate - "Great!" I thought.  As usual, it didn't work and two hours later and installing two other modules (googletrans and another one) I'm still trying to make this work.  I don't understand why this happens to me)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the package to your Python Interpreter? If not; go to File -> Settings -> Project -> Python Interpreter. Then click "+", and select google-trans-new. You can also check if it's installed correctly by typing `pip list` in cmd and check if it's listed.
Hope I helped :D